# What does 'Execute failed: (1062) Duplicate entry 'X' for key 'Y'' mean?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add `X` to some table in my DB, but I am getting this error. Even if `X` doesn't exist in the table, it say it's there. Although `X` is added to the DB, I want to get rid of this error. I don't know if it's relevant at all, but I'm using Mysqli's prepared statements and this error is printed using `$statement->errno." ".$statement->error`. Could someone explain this to me? Thanks.

UPDATE: this is the code:  `X = USER_USERNAME`

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS (USER_USERNAME, USER_EMAIL, USER_BIRTHDAY, USER_PASSWORD, USER_SALT, USER_IP, USER_ACTIVATION_CODE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,INET_ATON(?),?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('sssssss',$username,$email,$date,$hashed_password,$salt,$IP,$activation_code);
            $stmt->execute();
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
            }
            else {
                echo "ok";
            }
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE USERS:

```
 CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
 `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `USER_FIRSTNAME` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_LASTNAME` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_USERNAME` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_PASSWORD` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `LEVEL_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `USER_BIRTHDAY` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_EMAIL` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_GENDER` enum('M','W','U') CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_COUNTRY` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_LOCATION` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_ADDRESS` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_HOUSENUMBER` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_AVATAR` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_REGISTRATION_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `USER_ACTIVATION_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `USER_STATUS` enum('REGISTERED','ACTIVE','BANNED','NONACTIVE') CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_BANNED_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `USER_LATEST_LOGIN` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `USER_EXP` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `USER_DESCRIPTION` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
 `USER_ACTIVATION_CODE` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `USER_SALT` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `USER_IP` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `USER_REMEMBER_KEY` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `USER_USERNAME` (`USER_USERNAME`),
 UNIQUE KEY `USER_EMAIL` (`USER_EMAIL`),
 KEY `LEVEL_ID` (`LEVEL_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: can you show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE X`?

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are trying to insert or update a value violating a constraint (like PK or UK), for example

if your Table have ID an it's a PK or a Unique Key, you can only have ONE UNIQUE VALUE... it's not possible no repeated....

with a Unique Key you can have Null... but never repeat values in the same column, because you will be breaking the constraint... for more information take a look to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting that error then X *does* exist in the table. Apparently you have not noticed it, but it's there. (Check for things like trimmed spaces, and case sensitivity.)

If you don't get the error in phpMyAdmin then the query you think you are sending is not actually the query you are sending. Most likely you are sending blank for the field, and after you do it once, all further query are using the identical blank value.

Easiest way to check is delete everything from the table (copy it elsewhere first if you want). Then run the query and see what actually got inserted vs. what you expected to get inserted.

Comment: No it doesn't. X gets added to the table, but I keep getting this error. I'm 100% sure X doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You already defined a **Primary** or **Unique Key**, but again you tried to insert the same value. That time since already there exists a same value, it is not possible to have a redundant value for the primary key or unique key.

It is something like this. Consider you have a table with `id` and `name`, with `id` as `primary key`. You insert first row as:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Praveen');
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Kumar');
```

The second query violates the `id` uniqueness.

#### Solution: Try to truncate the table and then run the query again, if it is possible.

#### Some steps to try

1. Check for other fields with unique constraints being violated too.
2. See what query is getting generated.
3. Put the same query in **phpMyAdmin** and check.

Comment: I have ID set on "auto increment". ID is a primary key and 'X' is an unique key. And 'X' really doesn't exist!

Comment: Woah... But the only reason `Error 1062` is thrown is because of duplicating a unique constraint. Check for others too. See what query is getting generated. Put the same query in phpMyAdmin and check.

Comment: Oddly enough, I don't get the error when I execute the query in phpMyAdmin!

Comment: Woah! :P Can you share the PHP Code you have used?

Comment: By any chance you are inserting value to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field? Just leave it `null`.

Comment: No I don't insert anything as USER_ID (which is set on AUTO_INCREMENT), not even NULL! Should I do that? See my question for code.

Comment: We need the schema too. Can you please say the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE X`?

Comment: You have given 3 Unique Keys:
    PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`),
    UNIQUE KEY `USER_USERNAME` (`USER_USERNAME`),
    UNIQUE KEY `USER_EMAIL` (`USER_EMAIL`),
Make sure they are not getting affected.

Comment: I generally use `mysql_query()`. What I do is, I replace `mysql_query()` with `die()` and check it out with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: USER_ID is AUTO_INCREMENT, USER_USERNAME and USER_EMAIL don't exist when I try to insert. I'm 100% sure of that, because I'm running it on a test DB and it has only 5 entries. The weird thing is that it's added to DB despite the error. I guess I just don't print the error anymore :)

Comment: Ah!!! There's your problem. You cannot have more than one empty values in Unique key constraint! Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to insert a record with the ID (or some other field) 1 set, while such a record already exists in the table. The field that is the primary key must have a unique value for each record.

You could try a simple error check to avoid this error:

```
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT X from tablenme WHERE X = Y;");

if(mysql_num_rows($rows) > 0){
    echo 'Error Messege';
}else{
    insert...
}
```

where X is the primary key or foregin key column and Y is the value to be inserted in that column.

**EDIT:** Some of the problems that might have caused the problem may be that you have not specified certain columns that can't be null in you insert statement.
Like `LEVEL_ID` and `USER_REMEMBER_KEY`. They are set to `NOT NULL` but the values are not being inserted using the insert statement.

I also don't understand why you are inserting `'sssssss'` when the first column is `USER_USERNAME` and its corresponding value is `$username`. Do check that too.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b93c5)

Comment: The problem is something else, because when I try to insert the same X on phpMyAdmin, I don't get any errors.